# Limiting users to logging onto Samba domain only from specific machines

Tags: windows, networking, samba, domain-controller

I have Samba setup and running nicely as a primary domain controller with roaming profiles. Currently users can log on to the domain controller from any machine in the network.

However, I want to know if its possible to prevent users from logging on from *specific* machines on the network (for example, there may be certain machines that only a subset of domain users should have access to). I've searched high and low but can't seem to find anything that meets this requirement.

I initially thought I could do something like this in my `smb.conf`:

```
[netlogon]
  root preexec = /srv/scripts/check-logon.sh %U %m
  root preexec close = yes
```

..and then get the `check-logon.sh` script to return 1 if the user is not permitted to logon from that particular machine. However, all this does is to prevent access to the NETLOGON share (which stops the `logon script` from being executed) but doesn't actually prevent the domain logon.

Is this even possible?